# How to pattern match in scala 2.13?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, scala-2.13

I have the following regex, that I would like to pattern match in *Scala 2.13*.
The regex:

```
\/brokers\/ids\/\d{1,}$
```

The following string, that is going to be validate:

```
scala> ("echo dump" #| "nc localhost 32773" #| "grep brokers").!!
res2: String =
"       /brokers/ids/1
"
```

How can I do it in Scala 2.13?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Scala 2.13* introduced interpolated string patterns, so you could avoid using regex and just do:

```
"/brokers/ids/1" match {
  case s"/brokers/ids/$ids" => ids //returns 1
}
```

Comment: Looking for document link for this but couldn't find.