# regex to find only date from a string

Tags: regex, scala

I have a string with below pattern. I want to only extract date from the string.

```
199.120.110.23 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /medium/1/ HTTP/1.0" 200 6245
199.120.110.22 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400] "GET /medium/2/ HTTP/1.0" 200 3985
199.120.110.21 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400] "GET /medium/3/stats/stats.html HTTP/1.0" 200 4085
```

Expected output

```
01/Jul/1995
01/Jul/1995
01/Jul/1995
```

Currently I am extracting with two steps.

1. extract everything between square bracket. `\[(.*?)\]`
2. extract the first 11 letters from the first step output string. `^.{1,11}`

Wondering if it can be done in one step.

Answer (score 2):

In Scala 2.13 consider pattern matching with [interpolated string patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57090240/5205022), for [example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JyfnHUUCRBCzuwY4rJFvfg)

```
List(
  """199.120.110.23 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /medium/1/ HTTP/1.0" 200 6245""",
  """199.120.110.22 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400] "GET /medium/2/ HTTP/1.0" 200 3985""",
  """199.120.110.21 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400] "GET /medium/3/stats/stats.html HTTP/1.0" 200 4085"""
) collect { case s"${head}[${day}/${month}/${year}:${tail}" => s"$day/$month/$year" }
```

outputs

```
res1: List[String] = List(01/Jul/1995, 01/Jul/1995, 01/Jul/1995)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't on Scala 2.13 yet, standard regex patterns still work.

```
val dateRE = "\\[([^:]+):".r.unanchored
List(
  """199.120.110.23 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /medium/1/ HTTP/1.0" 200 6245""",
  """199.120.110.22 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400] "GET /medium/2/ HTTP/1.0" 200 3985""",
  """199.120.110.21 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400] "GET /medium/3/stats/stats.html HTTP/1.0" 200 4085"""
) collect { case dateRE(date) => date }
//res0: List[String] = List(01/Jul/1995, 01/Jul/1995, 01/Jul/1995)
```