# Scala: Pick items from Map based on a condition

Tags: scala

I have the following map

```
val typeMap = Map(
  "Sample1" -> "a.type1",
  "Sample2" -> "a.type2",
  "Sample3" -> "b.type1",
  "Sample4" -> "b.type2",
  "Sample5" -> "b.type3",
  "Sample6" -> "c.type1",
  "Sample7" -> "c.type2",
  "Sample8" -> "c.type2",
  "Sample9" -> "d.type1"
)
```

I need to pick all Samples that are not of type `"a.XXX"`

So my expected output should be a list with values

`Sample3, Sample4, Sample5, Sample6, Sample7, Sample8, Sample9`

Comment: What have you tried? Why it didn't work? Did you check out the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html)? Have you even made any basic scala tutorial? - Hint you need `filter` + `keys`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez
This is what I've done. Not sure if this is the most elegant way of doing it
`typeMap.filter(x => !x._2.contains("a.")).keys.toList`

Comment: Yeah that is fine. You may also do this to be a little bit more efficient: `typeMap.view.filterNot { case (_, value) => value.startsWith("a.") }.keysIterator.toList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [`collect`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html#collect%5BK2,V2%5D(pf:PartialFunction%5B(K,V),(K2,V2)%5D):CC%5BK2,V2%5D) with [interpolated string patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57090240/5205022)

```
typeMap collect { case (key, s"$x.$y") if x != "a" => key }
```

---

As a side-note, in Scala, perhaps confusingly, `filter` means "filter in" whilst `filterNot` means "filter out"

```
typeMap.filter    { case (_, value) => !value.startsWith("a") }.keys  // keep in elements satisfying the condition
typeMap.filterNot { case (_, value) =>  value.startsWith("a") }.keys  // keep out elements satisfying the condition
```